# Need to understand my error message to move forward

Tags: python

I am trying to use the following to retrieve stock data from Yahoo.  can anyone tell me why this is not working? I would be super grateful for reply

## here is my input

```
import pandas_datareader as pdweb
from pandas_datareader import data, wb
import datetime
prices = pdweb.get_data_yahoo(['CVX', 'XOM','BP'],  start=datetime.datetime(2010,1,1), end=datetime.datetime(2013,1,1)) ,
['Adj Close']
prices.head()
```

## here is the error message

```
AttributeError                            Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-9-95b02a209848> in <module>()
----> 1 prices = pdweb.get_data_yahoo(['CVX', 'XOM','BP'],  start=datetime.datetime(2010,1,1), end=datetime.datetime(2013,1,1)) ,
      2 ['Adj Close']
      3 
      4 prices.head()

AttributeError: 'tuple' object has no attribute 'head'
```

Comment: Looks like `pdwed.get_data_yahoo` returns a tuple (which is similar to a list). A tuple does not have a `.head()` method, hence the `AttributeError`. If you are looking for the first element in the tuple, try indexing it with `[0]`

Answer (score 0):

It looks like the function you are calling is returning a tuple. And it looks like you want to access an instance of the class pdweb. To do this do:

```
P = pdweb() 
Tuple = p.get_data_yahoo() 
P.head()
```

Just a suggestion, I don't know how this library works, but I hope that this helps!

Edit:

Actually, as inspectorg4det said, since it's a tuple and not a list you would use tuple[index] to get an element. I do not know what I was thinking when I saw this question.